# Setting nullable TimeSpan in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I am creating a `Style` for the Player from MediaPlayerFramework and in this XAML style I want to set two properties (`SkipAheadInterval` and `SkipBackInterval`) which are of type `TimeSpan?`.

I tried

```
<Setter Property="SkipAheadInterval" Value="00:00:20.00" />
```

But I am getting

```
Cannot assign to nullable type on property SkipAheadInterval
```

Is there a way to do it in XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a ValueConverter and handling the nullable within the ValueConverter scope?

Comment: Any way to do it without the ValueConverter? It is a static value I want to set, using a ValueConverter does not seem "clean"

Comment: You can pass in the static value as a parameter to your converter.

Comment: At this time, I do not have an altertnative solution / workaround for your question.